# PHP WSDL generation is not supported yet

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i'm newbie in SoapServer and here is my found simple document and sample code about that. after generation SoapServer i get this Result :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>WSDL generation is not supported yet</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is my simple WSDL source code:

**Description:** my file name in local host is: wsdl_sample1.php

```
<?php
class MyAPI {

    function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
$options=array('uri'=>'http://localhost/wsdl_sample1.php?wsdl');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL,$options);
$server->setClass('MyAPI');
$server->handle();
echo "SOAP Server started";
?>
```

how to change this code to resolve problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The url (`http://localhost/wsdl_sample1.php?wsdl`) that you are providing should point to a valid WSDL file ( a tutorial on WSDL can be found [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/wsdl/index.html) )

PHP natively does not support WSDL generation. Zend Framework's classes however, do:  See [Zend Framework's Zend_Soap_Autodiscover](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html)

Otherwise you are stuck with creating your own wsdl. You might get some use out of online WSDL generators like [Online WSDL Generator](http://marin.jb.free.fr/wsdl/) to help you out a bit.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks sir. i want to use `wsimport` to generate functions for java for `wsdl` from SoapServer. my binding soap is `RPC` and after change that to `document` i get error both of chages. please help me to create or define correctly `encoding` for that. my simple template of SoapServer. http://paste.debian.net/115861/

Comment: I wish I could help you further, but after enduring the pains of SOAP for too long trying to get things to work in PHP, i forgot all about it and switched to a REST service. I can't help you with the quirks of SOAP itself. My knowledge ends at PHP's support of it.

Comment: can you fix my `wsdl` xml template file? i can chage PHP code but problem is in xml of my link. problem is: `[ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported. 
SOAP extension element on line 57 in http://localhost/wsdl1/index.php?wsdl has use="encoded" "`

Comment: Native ZendServer is rather limited. The Zend Framework soap classes are much better. Check out "http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.soap.server.html". You can get the neccesary files from the Zend Framework download (you dont need the entire framework, although you -do- need to included the required classes and their dependencies).

Comment: your introducing could not found. `A 404 error occurred
Page not found.`

Comment: Weird comment system. Here you go `http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.soap.server.html`

Comment: and if the uri pointing to good wsdl and the error continue to be here ? what the solution i'm stuck ?